# Emulator: Unexpected feature list: MultiDisplay VulkanNullOptionalStrings YUV420888toNV21 YUVCache

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-emulator

My android emulator showing error & not opening.
If someone helped, I am very thankful.

> Emulator: WARNING: unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
>
> Emulator: Unexpected feature list: MultiDisplay VulkanNullOptionalStrings YUV420888toNV21 YUVCache
>
> Gradle build finished in 11 s 518 ms
>
> ADB rejected shell command (getprop): closed
>
> Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: Thanks I'm not the only one. Do you have Hyper-V enabled? Did you upgrade your Android Studio / AVD in the last 3 days?

Comment: Same issue on Ryzen 3700X. Installing a fresh emulator with API 28 works fine.

Comment: Same situation, API 29 weird, API 28 seems to be ok.

Comment: Try using another version of Android system image. It works for me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have Dell G5 5587 with Win10 and I have exactly same issue from yesterday morning. After some updates to Android studio emulator stop working and crash on start up. I was trying to install Android.Q (API 29) x86 and x86_64 versions everything without any success. I try to change GPU to `auto`, `software`, `hardware`, change amount of RAM and all with the same crash result.

**Unfortunatelly I can't say  what to do to resolve the issue but i try to install new Virtual Device with Android Pie (API 28) with default settings and it's working so at least I can continue with my work till issue is resolved.**

Based on the error message I think it's connect somehow to graphic card itself (I have Nvidia Geforce MAXQ 1060) or graphic drivers (notice that nvidia control center icon suddenly disapper from startup icons).

Comment: I can't start the emulator either with a difference error, but when I tried the Android Pie 28, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem, you have to update your emulator in sdk manager:

1.launch sdk manager

2.settings->appearance and behavior->system settings->android sdk

3.SDK Tools

4. Update Android Emulator

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me when I was trying to run the API 29 emulator with Hyper-V instead of HAXM. To work around it, I turned off Hyper-V and installed HAXM.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

29 is partially installed and we can do nothing about it except to wait for the big update...

Comment: A senior android app developer suggested me "always use one level lower than the current API level in Emulator". current - 29, Emulator - 28.