# (Vulkan 1.0 APIs missing from instance) when launching Android Emulator(Q API 29) via Android Studio 3.5 and 3.6 Canary 9

Tags: android, android-emulator

I created three AVDs base on Android Q (API 29), using these system images:
 Android 10(Google Play), Android 10(Google APIs), Android 10.

All of these emulators failed to launch.
With the following error:

```
18:38   Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_0 check failed: vkCreateInstance not found

18:38   Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_0 check failed: vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties not found

18:38   Emulator: VK_VERSION_1_0 check failed: vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties not found

18:38   Emulator: createOrGetGlobalVkEmulation: Warning: Vulkan 1.0 APIs missing from instance

18:38   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have referred to this link:
[Emulator: Unexpected feature list: MultiDisplay VulkanNullOptionalStrings YUV420888toNV21 YUVCache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57424137/emulator-unexpected-feature-list-multidisplay-vulkannulloptionalstrings-yuv420)
But this issue is different from my issue.

I tried in Android Studio 3.5, and Android Studio 3.6 Canary 9, the latest version in stable and preview channel. Both end with the same result.

https://source.android.google.cn/devices/graphics/implement-vulkan
According to this page, Vulkan 1.0 should already exists since Android 7.0, I have no idea why Vulkan 1.0 is missing on Android 10.

Or should I just wait for the newer version of system image after Google officially release Android 10?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue on my system - Ubuntu 19.10 and Android Studio 3.5.3. Except I had a "Vulkan 1.1 APIs missing from instance" error and my emulator was running slow.

**The issue is not with the emulator, it's with your host system. Your host system doesn't have support for the Vulkan APIs that the new Android 10 emulator uses.**

To fix this, I had to install a newer version of the mesa packages from a [third-party PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kisak/+archive/ubuntu/kisak-mesa).

The steps to do so:

1. run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa` to add the PPA to your system.
2. run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade`. This should download and install the newer mesa packages from the PPA.

I rebooted my system just to be safe, and the emulator runs fine and smooth now.

Comment: not working here. still getting the same error: Vulkan 1.1 APIs missing from device

Comment: Worked for me, but only after I rebooted my laptop.

Comment: not working for me also despite rebooting the laptop.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why that's happening (it was happening to me to using API 29). I cloned the device in the AVD Manager and dropped the API down to 28 (Pie, Android 9) and I was able to successfully launch my app again.

Comment: I did the same and it worked too, you figure 10.0 is a big release, perhaps lots of new stuff.

Comment: For me, AVD using system image Android 10(Google APIs) is launching fine. But using system image Android 10(Google Play) is throwing the same error. So dropping down the API is not a solution i guess if one specifically wants to use Android 10(Google APIs) AVD.

Comment: @Josh Hw did you 'clone the device in AVD Manager and drop the API down to 28'?

Comment: @AhmedGhrib In Android Studio go to Tools > AVD Manager and select your AVD. Then click the down arrow under the Actions column and choose Duplicate. Change the Android SDK version and click Finish.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues that were not fixed with the installation hints above.

I finally solved the problem following this instructions to Configure VM acceleration on Linux: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation

My problem turned out to be wrong user-groups configuration. The following commands finally made it work for me:

> $ sudo adduser  libvirtd
>
> $ sudo chown root:libvirtd /dev/kvm

Answer (score 1):

Credit to Anthony who posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68344341/11029770). Thought it would be helpful here, as it immediately solved the problem for me without any impact to performance.

> You need to disable the Vulkan apps to talk to the emulator.
>
> To do so, just create the file ~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini (it doesn't exist already) and add the following lines:
>
> ```
> Vulkan = off
> GLDirectMem = on
> ```
>
> (For Windows users the path should be C:\Users%USER%.android\advancedFeatures.ini)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you have to update your emulator in sdk manager:

1.launch sdk manager

2.settings->appearance and behavior->system settings->android sdk

3.SDK Tools

4. Update Android Emulator

   [image]

Comment: same here. still have the problem

Comment: did you updated android emulator to the highest version ? Try reinstall the awd image or use lower version of awd

Comment: yes, I tried it with the latest version of the emulator but no luck

Comment: When I switch API down to 28 it's working fine only with 29 I have this problem

Answer (score 0):

### Windows

Had to manually install [Nvidia Drivers](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us), in order to update Vulkan Runtime. (Nvidia Gforce Experience not needed)