# Android emulator Failed to create Vulkan instance

Tags: android, android-emulator, vulkan

When creating new Android emulator in Ubuntu shows following error, does this affect my vulkan game development?

```
queryCoreProfileSupport: swap interval not found
emulator: ERROR: VkCommonOperations.cpp:496: Failed to create Vulkan instance.
emulator: WARNING: Ignoring invalid http proxy: Bad format: invalid port number (must be decimal)
```

My AVD device specification are added below.

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't call this a duplicate, but this potentially is a similar scenario https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57771201/vulkan-1-0-apis-missing-from-instance-when-launching-android-emulatorq-api-29.  Also just found this https://github.com/flathub/com.google.AndroidStudio/issues/45.  Couldn't immediately see the solution besides downgrading android api version.  If this works you might want to just self answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your os seems ubuntu, try installing the graphic driver as below them restart the computer.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Comment: Got error No drivers found for automatic installation.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding

```
emulator: ERROR: VkCommonOperations.cpp:496: Failed to create Vulkan instance.
```

Upon fresh installation of Ubuntu, you're given the option to download and run proprietary drivers. There seems to be some compatibility issues with Android Studio Emulators running API 29, and these drivers.

Until the open source drivers (or Android Studio) fixes this, your only option is to run that proprietary code.

**:-(**

---

If you still want to, you can open up your Application Tray, then select `Software & Updates`. Navigate to the `Additional Drivers` tab, select the latest version of the proprietary drivers, then `Apply Changes`.

While it's doing its thing, a menu will appear where you'll set a password if you have UEFI Secure Boot. Set the password and let it finish applying changes.

When it's done, reboot your machine.

You'll be prompted during the boot process to `Press any key to perform MOK management`

Select the `Enroll Mok Key` option, then `Continue`, then `Reboot`.

You're done.

If you ever want to go back, just go back into `Software & Updates` and elect the open source drivers option.

Comment: Even with proprietary driver I have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens,it may take sometime to open your app(i am not sure if it will be able to open your app),but after waiting sometime,if app not opens in your emulator,delete the avd and download again and re-install adv.
My emulator ran quite fine for long,but suddenly i faced this error,i searched in internet but couldn't find any perfect solution,then i followed the way(i said already),and succed but not sure wether it will help you or not,but u can try

Answer (score -3):

Just create a new device in AVD Manager.