# Emulator - Failed to Create Vulcan Instance - API 29

Tags: android, android-emulator

As per the title when running emulator based on google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 29) the emulator opens then immediately closes.

```
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: VkCommonOperations.cpp:496: Failed to create Vulkan instance.
Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

The closest I can find is [Android emulator Failed to create Vulkan instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58059822/android-emulator-failed-to-create-vulkan-instance) but its ubuntu. 
No response here https://github.com/flathub/com.google.AndroidStudio/issues/45
And none of these answers work   [(Vulkan 1.0 APIs missing from instance) when launching Android Emulator(Q API 29) via Android Studio 3.5 and 3.6 Canary 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57771201/vulkan-1-0-apis-missing-from-instance-when-launching-android-emulatorq-api-29)

Running Studio 3.6.2, Windows 10, SDK 29, Emulator 30.0.5

Ideas? Thanks in advance.