# Android Studio Emulator error "The emulator process for AVD was killed"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

This is the error I'm getting:

**The emulator process for AVD Pixel_XL_API_30 was killed**.

All virtual devices don't run. I've tried deleting the directory for them and then creating new ones.

Comment: please check my answer below. it worked for me

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to disable the Vulkan apps to talk to the emulator.

To do so, just create the file `~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini` (it doesn't exist already) and add the following lines:

> Vulkan = off
> GLDirectMem = on

(For Windows users the path should be `C:\Users\%USER%\.android\advancedFeatures.ini`)

Comment: Couldn't run an emulator for APIs 29 and 30 getting the error in the question. This lonely answer in a dark corner of Stack Overflow solved it for me. Thank you.

Comment: This seems working also on Linux for Emulator version 32. For an alternative see also: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-troubleshooting#cannot-open