# Google Chrome open with white screen on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to run latest version of `Google Chrome` on `Android emulator`, but after upgrading it from the Play Store, it always opened as a white screen. I even tried to download Edge chromium but had same issue!

I tried to Cold Boot, Wipe data, and create a new emulator, but had same issue. It was working before 1 week, and not sure if there is any update just brake things. I can see that last Chrome update was on January 4th, 2022.

Environment:

- **Emulator**: Pixel 4 API 30
- **Android Version**: 11
- **OS**: Windows 11
- **Chrome version:** 97.0.4692.70

Screenshot for the white screen:
[image: Chrome white screen]

Any ideas will be much appreciated

Comment: I don't see how your question is related to programming. Therefore this seems to be better suited on https://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you @Robert , I saw some similar questions but the solution did not work for me, and I thought this can be a good place to ask. I will make sure to use the other mentioned website.

Comment: @Ebraheem Did you solve it? I got the same problem

Comment: @wallef, unfortunately not. I had to use the older version that come with the emulator

Answer (score 26):

Create or open the `advancedFeatures.ini` file.

macOS/Linux: `~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini`

Windows: `C:\Users\%USER%\.android\advancedFeatures.ini`

Add the following lines:

```
Vulkan = off
GLDirectMem = on
```

Please note that `advancedFeatures.ini` may be deleted during major emulator upgrades.

Sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70842795/4329861

And

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68344341/4329861

Comment: Please be aware that advancedFeatures.ini *may* be deleted when Emulator do major upgrades.

Comment: This worked for me, emulating Pixel 4/5 on Android 12.1. Thank you.

Comment: This seems working also on Linux for Emulator version 32. For an alternative see also: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-troubleshooting#cannot-open