# Android emulator failing to start

Tags: android, flutter

I am attempting to start android emulator (using various methods, AVD, command line with flutter emulator or *VSCODE* extension) and each way I do it... it doesn't work.

For example if I launch the emulator through VSCODE using `Debug->start debugging`. The emulator seems to start... meaning I get the giant phone come up. However, it only stays there for about 30 seconds then disappears. When I do this from the command line using `flutter emulators --launch Pixel_2_API_29` same result... also same result from AVD...

The frustrating part is I don't get any error messages...

The closest thing I get to an error message is in *VSCODE* it says

> Failed to launch Pixel 2 API 29: Error: Emulator didn't connect within
>   60 seconds

Which isn't very  helpful.

Is there any log that i can view that may have information on this?

Comment: Did you check if you have enough free space on disk?

Comment: I do. Interestingly enough though.. when i start i didn't i made room and things are fine on that front now 60G free.

Comment: and I guess you tried `emulator -avd <emulator> -verbose`, right?

Comment: umm.. no i haven't. i dont have a command "emulator" on my command line?

Comment: i have "flutter emulator -v" ?

Comment: This seams to be my issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57424137/emulator-unexpected-feature-list-multidisplay-vulkannulloptionalstrings-yuv420

Comment: `emulator` should come with Android Studio I guess. I'd try make it work and also update your emulator and it's API. And if you find the problem please share it!