# Cannot launch Device "The emulators process for AVD Nexus_6_API_28 has terminated"

Tags: android, windows, intel

I had a problem with Android Studio.
Cannot launch emulator, the error is: "The emulators process for AVD Nexus_6_API_28 has terminated"

For better diagnostic, I desired view a log of error but cannot see anything. It´s possible for Android?

I tryed wit this post but not work:
1- [Emulator: Unexpected feature list: MultiDisplay VulkanNullOptionalStrings YUV420888toNV21 YUVCache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57424137/emulator-unexpected-feature-list-multidisplay-vulkannulloptionalstrings-yuv420)

2- [Failed to launch emulator: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677874/failed-to-launch-emulator-error-emulator-didnt-connect-within-60-seconds)

My system is:
Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 (May 18, 2022)

Mi PC:
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz   2.30 GHz
Windows 10 Pro

Any idea? Thank

Comment: I find a solution and post it, but a moderator delete solution.
I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was low on memory. I had 8GB of RAM and there were Google Chrome, Android Studio and few Terminals and background processes running, occupying 95% of my memory. I closed chrome and few other background processes and emulator started successfully. Sometimes I needed to restart Android Studio to run emulator.